# Smali Folder Without A Proper Name

Tags: android, apk, smali

I was trying to reverse-engineering Android APK file through the use of the magical apktool. However, I notice that under the smali folder, there are folders without a proper name, i.e:
a/a/a/a/a/b.smali and b/b/b/b/b/a.smali
I have previously try to reverse engineer my own APK files and realize the folder structure are identical to how I organize my packages. Anyway, I do not have any NDK compiled library files. So, I am wondering what are these a/a/a/a/a smali folders and are they by any chance related to .so file?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reverse engineering software, probably in violation of it's licensing terms and conditions, and not about creating software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reverse-engineer a ***release*** build of your own apk. You will see the same *a.a.ab()* stuff. One of the steps in making a release build is obfuscation -- you see what it does. Please note that there is also apk signing, so a modified apk cannot be re-built *and* re-signed (unless you have the publisher's key).

And, BTW, there's https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) is the reason for that. it is used to make the code obfuscated and secure against the reverse-engineering.

What Proguard does?:

```
The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names.
```